# How to get out from event function (onclick event)?

Tags: javascript

How to get out from event function (onclick event)?

```
document.onclick = function (event) {
    if ( event.target.getAttribute("id") == 'chess') {alert('You miss cell!'); };
    if (prevCell != undefined) {
        prevCell.classList.remove('red');
        }
//....
    }
    //.....
```

With the term 'get out', I mean to stop this function and wait for new onclick event.

Comment: add `return false;` after `alert('You miss cell!');`

Comment: `return;`? What do you mean by “get out”? End the function?

Comment: return false ! Great!  Thanks Subhir! Someone need to rest a little...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write return statement where you want to stop function.

Example:

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (){
If(flag) return

// Do some other work

Return
})

Return statement immediately stops function execution